# How to remove redundant contents in json by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[{...  
  {'adminregion': {'id': 'SAS', 'iso2code': '8S', 'value': 'South Asia'},
      'capitalCity': 'Kabul',
      'id': 'AFG',
      'incomeLevel': {'id': 'LIC', 'iso2code': 'XM', 'value': 'Low income'},
      'iso2Code': 'AF',
      'latitude': '34.5228',
      'lendingType': {'id': 'IDX', 'iso2code': 'XI', 'value': 'IDA'},
      'longitude': '69.1761',
      'name': 'Afghanistan',
      'region': {'id': 'SAS', 'iso2code': '8S', 'value': 'South Asia'}},
...}]
```

The above is a part of my JSON file from world bank collected by API, but I don't need every single column. I would like to know how to delete the column that I don't actually need?

I am happy with the result below:

```
[{...  
  {
      'id': 'AFG',
      'incomeLevel': 'Low income',
      'name': 'Afghanistan',
      'region': 'South Asia'},
...}]
```

Comment: Single quoted strings are not standard json, have you already converted the data you posted to a python dictionary? You may get more help if you attempt some code yourself and post that attempt with your question along with a brief explanation of what you don't understand.

Comment: @benvc Hi, thanks for your reply. I would like to know, what if the data is downloaded with this format? should I also change it? Also, when I open it in notebook by clicking its file name, it is double quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple *for-loop* approach given that the `json` object you provided is the format for each object in the array.

```
res = []

for item in data:
    id_ = item.get('id')
    income = item.get('incomeLevel').get('value')
    name = item.get('name')
    region = item.get('region').get('value')
    final = {'id': id_, 'incomeLevel': income, 'name': name, 'region': region}
    res.append(final)

print(res)

[{'id': 'AFG',
  'incomeLevel': 'Low income',
  'name': 'Afghanistan',
  'region': 'South Asia'}]
```

Or another approach would be:

```
keys = ['id', 'incomeLevel', 'name', 'region']
res = []

for item in data:
    out = {}
    for k, v in item.items():
        if k in keys:
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                out.update({k: v.get('value')})
            else:
                out.update({k: v})
    res.append(out)

print(res)

[{'id': 'AFG',
  'incomeLevel': 'Low income',
  'name': 'Afghanistan',
  'region': 'South Asia'}]
```